# MINGW32 orphan console window

Tags: windows-7, console, mingw

I was installed Git extensions in Windows 7, which have a `Git Bash` console which title starts with "MINGW32" so it is running under MINGW.

Today I found that such a window became a zombie -- I cannot close it in any way.

Attempts:

1. Close button -- does not do anything
2. Right click task icon and "Close window" -- does not work as well
3. Bring task manager to "Application" tab and "End Task" -- does not work again
4. "Go to process" to figure out which process it is -- tab switched, but no highlighted process was shown (even when I hit "show processes for all users")
5. Try to figure out which process it is -- No hint for me to do so. simply could't find it.

[This could be a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335671/how-to-close-an-orphaned-console-window-that-was-opened-from-within-visual-stu) - I forgotten how I created this window, it could be Visual studio Git extension (for 2010) that initialized this window.

Can anyone help me figure what is happening?

Comment: Seems like a bug of windows console subsystem. BTW, try ConEmu as alternative terminal.